# how to check if variable is null in dart?

Tags: dart, dart-null-safety

I am new to dart. I want to do something like this. But editor says it is 'unnecessary_null_comparison'. What is the best way in dart to do something like this?

```
 EventType? et = dbHandler.getEventType(widget.eventName) as EventType;
 if (et != null) {
   dbHandler.insertEventType(eventType);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `dbHandler.getEventType(widget.eventName)` returns a nullable value you should use `as EventType?`. Then your code should work as expected.

```dart
EventType? et = dbHandler.getEventType(widget.eventName) as EventType?;
if (et != null) {
  dbHandler.insertEventType(et);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dart has [sound null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety) so when you casted it to EventType using `as EventType`, it is not nullable by definition, that's why it's saying the null comparison is unnecessary because it'll always evaluate to true.